# HPE DL380P Riser compatibility: Gen8/Gen9/Gen10

Tags: hpe

Does anybody know if the Risers from the HPE DL380P Gen8/Gen9/Gen10 Servers have some/total/no (downward/upward) compatibility?

They all apparently connect to two PCIe x16 in serie available on the motherboard.
I overlapped the images of the connectors it appears they match 1:1, although with some pins merged together in the Gen10 Riser.
Unfortunately I do not have a Gen10 Riser to physically compare them and cannot find any information about the pin mapping.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the correct part as indicated by the QuickSpecs for the intended model.

Gen10 server hardware is not meant to be used with older risers or cages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  I know that in a professional environment we should use only recommended parts. But that wasn't the question. Are they compatible? I mean, can I put a Gen10 Riser on a Gen9 Server? Will it work? Or have they different PCIe Standards, 3 vs 4 for example?

Comment: Dude... Just don't.